# Cannot find a 1-argument function named Q{http://exslt.org/math}max(). External function calls have been disabled

Tags: function, math, xslt, exslt

I'm trying to transform a letter based on my XSLT and it is giving me an error:

> Cannot find a 1-argument function named Q{http://exslt.org/math}max().
> External function calls have been disabled.

I'm using **XSLT 1.0** by the way.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
```

I tried changing the `xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"` to `xalan math` but still getting the error:

> External function calls have been disabled.

Any idea if it's permissions related or probably a properties file?

Comment: This looks like a Saxon error message. If you're using Saxon, it surely makes sense to move forwards to XSLT 20/3.0 so you have math functions build-in, rather than relying on extensions.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'll discuss it with our Cloud Engineering team as I don't have access to those.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I got my answer from Saxonica. exsl:math and other functions except common are only available in Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE and is not available in what we have currently in the server which is Saxon-HE.
I'll discuss this finding with our network/system team. Thanks for all the help and tips Conal and Michael.

Comment: Saxon-HE has full support for XPath math functions https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/functions/math/ and of course any XPath functions https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/, I doubt there is anything in the exsl:math namespace that you can't these days implement using a standard XPath 3.1 function.

Comment: If you're using Saxon then you can just switch to XSLT 3 and use the standard XPath `max` function!

Answer (score 0):

What XSLT processor are you running? Is it Saxon?

If so, you'll want to check this configuration setting is enabled:
https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!configuration/config-features@ALLOW_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS

If you don't know what the processor is (e.g. if embedded in some other software), trying running this stylesheet:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <version
      vendor="{system-property('xsl:vendor')}"
      version="{system-property('xsl:version')}"
      vendor-url="{system-property('xsl:vendor-url')}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Conal. Will try that out and update. Cheers